# When I run this Python 2.7 code I get the output "k" immediately . Shouldn't "k" be printed after 5 seconds?

Tags: numpy, opencv3.0

```
import numpy
import cv2

vid=cv2.VideoCapture("katy.avi")
cv2.waitKey(5000)
if vid.isOpened():
    print "k"
```

I am running this code on windows 8.1, Python 2.7 and numpy 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember that pressing a key will trigger the end of waitKey(), thus skipping the 5s

Comment: Ya, but I didn't press any key

Comment: Too bad, I'm always a fan of ghosts playing with my keyboard. (Or virtual keyboards messing with my setup). Shall I delete the answer ?